# R read SQL in multiple encoding store and work in utf-8

Tags: mysql, r, encoding, utf-8

my Rstudio Project and System Setup is on UTF8

sadly my database contains some old legacy tables in latin1

i want to pull the latin table into my UTF8 workflow
without killing all my öüä :D

some scripts later on in my workflow dont like mixed encoding.

```
### connect db
my_db <- dbPool(RMySQL::MySQL(),
%%%% my private DB-credentials %%%% )

### read data
my_latin<-my_db %>%  dbGetQuery("SELECT * FROM legacy_sqltable;")
my_utf8<-my_db %>%  dbGetQuery("SELECT * FROM new_sqltable;")

### join data
fulldata_in_utf8 <- full_join(my_latin,my_utf8)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can adjust the encoding of a variable in R with the function iconv or Encoding.

[Here](https://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/base/html/iconv.html) is the link to the page. The following function works for changing the encoding of your dataframe to latin1 or just making sure that the r knows that is latin-1

```
Encoding(my_lating) <- "latin1"
```

If you want to successfully join them, I suggest to encode the data frames to the same encoding.

Answer (score 4):

Alternative answer for MS SQL Server:

If you're using `odbc` or `DBI::dbConnect` to connect to your database, you simply need to specify the database encoding. Everything else should be automatic.

e.g.

```r
con <-DBI::dbConnect(odbc::odbc(), DSN_name,
                UID=<username>,
                PWD=<password>,
                Database=<database>,
                encoding="latin1") # <---- Specify the database encoding here!
```

Answer (score 0):

1. Specify that R will work only in utf8 (or utf8mb4)
2. MySQL, as it reads a latin1 column, will convert the characters to utf8.

You would have to work *harder* to get latin1 bytes from some `SELECTs` and utf8 bytes from other `SELECTs`.

I don't happen to know the R way of establishing the client as using utf8 during the connection, but here is a way to do it after connecting:

```
rs <- dbSendQuery(con, 'SET NAMES utf8')
```

If you are `JOINing` a tables via columns with different `CHARACTER SETs` (or `COLLATIONs`), it may work.  (There are a few cases where it will spit at you, but they can be worked around.)

To do a blanket change of all the columns in a particular table:

```
 ALTER TABLE mytable CONVERT TO CHARACTER SET utf8mb4;
```

Note:  Outside MySQL, it is called `UTF-8`.  Inside MySQL it is either `utf8` (for the 3-byte subset) or `utf8mb4` (for the full `UTF-8` set).